# JavaFX 2 updating the model from network

Tags: tcp, network-programming, javafx

I am doing a application using JavaFX 2.  For the graphical interface part the MVP design pattern seems to fit well with JavaFX, but I would like to have some advice on how to update the model from the data coming from a tcp-ip messaging.  I would like to separate the model from all the socket creation and connection.  Is there a common pattern for that kind of application ?  What kind of layer can I add the manage all network stuff and messages ?  Thanks for advices.